# Program of Random distribution of vehicle speed

Tags: c++, statistics, transport

I'm not getting a way to use distribution curves for random number generation, that depicts the behavior of a real vehicle's speed. So, a random generator (of stdlib) in [0, 120] limit, generates numbers randomly. How can I distribute it on the basis of probability?

If the vehicle's speed is 80, then most of the time, it should be near 80, and the probability of a number too far from this should be low (distribution curve). For a normal distribution, both sides of mean have equal probability of occurrence which is 0.5, while for a skewed distribution it would be different. In this case I would need a skewed distribution, and I want to generate random numbers on this basis.

So, why do I need skewed distribution? Well, we can set this speed of 80 as a mean value and in this limit of [0, 120] it will generate a positively skewed distribution. At first, I want to write this model with this basic skewness of (120-80)/120 = 33% (right) and 66% (left); later I'll model it using a better PDF. At this point, I simply want to generate some numbers through probability distribution curves (PDFs).

Comment: Later, I want to use traffic to change the skewness of this curve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the boost library
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/skew_normal_dist.html

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/skew_normal.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main(){
// Setup generators
std::random_device rd;


// Sample from a uniform distribution i.e. [0,1)
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform_dist(0,1.0);

// Take a different value every time to generate probabilities from 0 to 1


auto skew_norm_dist = boost::math::skew_normal_distribution<double>(
    0, 1., 10.);

// Use the probability from the uniform distribution with the percent point
// function of the skew_normal
float probability = 0.99;
double skew_normal_sample_point = boost::math::quantile(skew_norm_dist, probability);
std::cout << "Sample point: " << skew_normal_sample_point << std::endl;
}
```

if you don't have the boost library you can download it or you can try use an online compiler that support boost like this one :
https://wandbox.org/

Comment: @umairmughal Please mark as answer if that helped !